# Optimize Mesh not working in import settings of model

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an issue between Blender and Unity. I try to import a mesh in OBJ from Blender to Unity but I can see that vertex order is not good in Unity.

I can see that there is a parameter called "Opitmize Mesh" in the model Import settings and I tried to set this parameter to "Nothing" for testing but when I apply, the parameter stay to "Everything", even if I restart Unity.

I also tried to force a value in the META file but it always reset to this : "meshOptimizationFlags: -1"
I'm using Unity 2020.3.8, I already tried in Unity 2020.3.1 too but same result.

Does anyone have an idea with this problem ?

Thanks !
[Option in import settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhmto.png)